# Losing Filter When Paging Back From Second Page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, filter, view

I have a list view of a task list with filters creating subsets of tasks (Archived, Constructing, Defect, Stabilizing, etc.). The default view has a limit that will return 100 items at a time when expanded. If I have 150 items in a particular filter, I can click the right arrow to see 101-150 which works fine, but when I click left arrow to return to items 1-100, the list loses its filter and begins displaying all items in the list. I had another user test with a custom filter, increasing the number of items returned, but if it's anything below the total number of items in the list, the problem occurs. That is, if there were 158 items and the custom view had a limit of 150, you could page over for 151-158, but when paging back the filter is lost from the view.

Is there a way to make the filters continue to apply when paging both forward and backward?

Comment: Are you using IE? If so, which version? Also, inspect your URL when paging forward and back. The URL ought to contain "?Paged=TRUE" when you're on subsequent pages. What are the differences within the URLs when paging is and is not working?

Comment: We're all using IE10. I don't see "?Paged=TRUE" at all, neither before nor after we encounter the issue.

Comment: IE10 32-bit, right? Also, are you at SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 2 or greater? (i.e. SharePoint build 14.0.7015.1000 or greater)

Comment: Yes to IE 10 32-bit, but my build version is 14.0.6029.1000. Sounds like that could be the issue, then?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 SP2 added [support for IE10](http://sharepointcandothat.com/sharepoint-2010-sp2/). I'm not certain that's the cause of your problem, but it might be. Can you test with IE9 or earlier? Also, can you please share your URLs (with sensitive details masked) for page1 and page2?

Comment: http://<internal server>/sites/<specific site>/LeadTeam/Lists/Dev%20Task%20List/AllItems.aspx is the URL both before and after the issue.

Comment: And I'm looking for someone with IE9... Looks like we've upgraded everyone to 10 or 11.

Comment: It appears that the same problem occurs in IE9, as well.